# How to get the value of the PeopleEditor in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery

I need to get the value of the `PeopleEditor` using JavaScript and jQuery.
following this article :

http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Using-JavaScript-jQuery-to-get-the-value-of-the-PeopleEditor-in-SP2013

I did exactly the same but i allways get the undefined value :

this is the html code :

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor AllowEmpty="true" ID="docReviewerUser"                            
            runat="server" MultiSelect="false" SelectionSet="User" Width="300px" />
```

and this is the JavaScript :

```
 var html = $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_docReviewerUser_upLevelDiv");
 var DocReviewerLoginName = $("#divEntityData", html).attr("key");
```

> DocReviewerLoginName = undefined .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using browser developer tool make sure the Id of the control is `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_docReviewerUser_upLevelDiv`

Another option is to use the id contains selector, which is not recommended

```
var html = $("[id*=docReviewerUser]");
var DocReviewerLoginName = $("#divEntityData", html).attr("key");
```

Comment: I sill get the same error after using `$("[id*=docReviewerUser]");`